# how to change max upload size of media file

Tags: media

I am using media module to add files to server and have given same access to others. Now I want to keep the upload size limit to 1 MB. Please let me know if any option to change this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried, what are your limitations? You should be able to change your php.ini if you have access per [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1161672).

Answer (score 1):

From your admin menu follow path as
 `Structure` >> `Content types`

You will see list of content types, click on `manage fields` for the one you have your media field to limit download size. Now you will see list of all your fields, click on edit link for the field you want to edit download size. Scroll down to find `Maximum upload size` textfield and set its value as 1 MB. By default it is set to a value allowed by your php.ini

Comment: Arpitr, this option is available only if the field type is image or file but not for media. I am using media file selector. See the 2nd screenshot uploaded by me.